# Using Objects Inside of jQuery Plugin Defaults

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, extend, javascript-objects

I have a codepen representing my question:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ibwvl

In the codepen, I create some simple plugin init functions and log out the settings when the app begins to run.

My question is, when I `console.log(app.settings)` I see my default object, along with the new options object merged together, but I do not see the last key inside of me defaults object (foo3). Is this because the default object is overwritten by the options object when `$.extend()` runs? If so, is there any way to merge nested objects with $.extend()?

For clarity:

default object:

```
var defaults = {
      test: 'foo',
      obj: {
        key1: null,
        key2: null,
        key3: 'foo3'
      }
    }
```

options object:

```
$('#foo').fooTest({
  obj: { 
    key1: 'foo1',
    key2: 'foo2'
  }
});
```

result when logging `app.settings`:

```
test: 'foo',
          obj: {
            key1: null,
            key2: null
          }
        }
```

Where did `key3` go?

Was it overwritten because of the options plugin defining the new obj as `obj: {}`?

If so, how can I use extend with nested objects and ensure they don't get overwritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you object is being overwritten. But fortunately, `$.extend` accept boolean as first parameter that allow deep extension.

Just do :

```
app.settings = $.extend(true, defaults, options); //this will override defaults
app.settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options); //this will not
//app.settings will be the same with both way
```

[Deep extension](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN)

Comment: Ugh, I even looked at the example in the docs and missed the 'true' in there. Thank you for the detailed answer and for the different variations. I was confused with both answers, one had the {} arg, and the other didn't, so this clears it up even more. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasur, that's what SO is there for!

Answer (score 3):

Use `deep` parameter of the `jQuery.extend` function. This will make extend function work recursive.

```
app.settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);
```

[From here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), you can find more examples about `jQuery.extend` function and its usage.

But be careful since it is added in jQuery v1.1.4 and as official documentation said, passing `false` for the first argument is not supported.